KiCad Pin Connected in Schematic But Fails to Route in PCB Layout
I’m working on a PCB design in KiCad and facing a routing issue with one of my component pins.
I want to connect 2 pins (11 and 12) of a DC:DC converter, then connect those 2 pins to a nearby capacitor (C4).
In the schematic these are connected, and the electrical connection looks fine. However, when I move to the PCB layout and try to route the pin, KiCad won’t let me draw a trace to it. It’s like the connection is blocked.
I have also noticed that the pins of the IC I can not route from or to do not have the purple frame around them like the rest of the components, maybe it has something to do with that?
What could be causing this, and how do I resolve it?

Your footprint has a problem. There's a polygon (the red thing that doesn't get highlighted, enclosing pads 10 and 11) on the copper layer that has either no net or some net other than CFLY1, and KiCad rightly refuses to connect CFLY1 to something that is not CFLY1. Fix the footprint and the issue will go away.
